TCXGrid unable to edit cell value
I have an application with a CXGrid on a form with a couple of cells. I need to be able to edit the value in a cell and needs to update the value right there on the cell. After reading up, I see that the 2 main properties to set to ensure editing is enabled are:
    GridMainDBTableView1.OptionsData.Editing := True;
    GridMainDBTableView1TotalCount.Editing   := True;

The column here that needs to edit the value is the TotalCount column. When I run the application and try to edit the value, I can see that the cell is editible, as my cursor appears inside the cell, I can hightlight the current integer value that is inside there, but I can never edit it. It never accepts any characters that I type, cannot even delete the current value to type a new value. Nothing more happens apart from the cursor appearing inside the cell, which is also an indication that the read-only is false. but nothing happens, I never get to change the value. Is there anything else I might have missed. I have read through multiple posts, on here and on DevExpress, but cannot get a working solution. Most if not all the solutions indicate that we need to change the values here above.
I have tried even putting in code on show to ensure that the columns editing is indeed set to True etc, but stil nothing changes. The only time I can see I change on the form is when I make it read-only, then my cursor does not appear in the cell anymore.
EDIT:
When I query the DB to get the values that needs to populate the grid, the column that I want to change the values in are queried in the following manner:
 ' ROUND(COALESCE(T0.TotalCount,0),T1.QtyDecimal) AS TotalCount, ';

Could this be the reason that it is not edible?

It's <column>.Options.editing that needs to be set . And the .readonly property of the FieldDef or TField must not be readonly. Also the <column>.Focusing must be set to True.

@FreddieBell both those options are set as you indicated in your reply. and nothing gets changed dynamically when the form with the grid is displayed.

The cursor appearing in a cell doesn't mean it's not read only, just that the contents are selectable which would be required to allow a user to copy part of cell value for example. There are numerous reasons a field might not be editable - from it being a calculated field (Tdataset level), a summary field (cxgrid) or the field not being editable from the database (whatever query and database sourced the data). Need to provide more details to avoid just enumerating all the ways a field might not be editable.

I had this exact problem recently.  I found that the database table component's readonly property was set to true, for some strange reason, likely an errant keystroke on my part when setting the properties of the TTable component.

@Brian You are indeed correct, I have made the properties that is required to be true, as stated above, to True, but still there is no editing happening. The DataSource is not read only, so I have no idea where else to look for a setting.

No database I know would return such a result column using a formula as editable.  I would suggest having the grid do the formatting with the query just returning the fields needed. Either as a format specifier for the grid column or in its OnGetDisplayText.

@Brian that is what I have also released, that you cannot edit a calculated field, the question then becomes, how do I save the updated value, with the correct decimal places. Now currently my value in TotalCount can now be changed, but it does not save the correct value inside the db, with the decimal requirement. It saves the value that I type in, the edited value, and saves that. I have tried putting code inside the GridMainDBTableView1CellValueChanged procedure, but it does not use the changed value, but ratherr the initial value stored in the. cell.

One place would be at the TDataSet (likely the query component in this case)  level using the OnChange or BeforePost event handlers.

So managed to resolve the issue, by following the advice from Brian above in the comments. So how I resolved the problem was by doing the following.
I made sure my select uses a standard column, not calculated. Then I passed the Decimal calculations part to the dataset, in this case an ADOQuery. And added my code to the beforePost event.
procedure TfrmSTK502.qrySTKSTakeSummaryBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if qrySTKSTakeSummary.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
  begin
    // Get QtyDecimal from your function
    var QtyDecimal := getQtyDecimal();

    // Round the value
    var RoundedValue := 
  RoundTo(qrySTKSTakeSummary.FieldByName('TotalCount').AsFloat, - QtyDecimal);

// Set the rounded value
    qrySTKSTakeSummary.FieldByName('TotalCount').AsFloat := RoundedValue;
  end;
end;

